# Disable certain Shopify apps on certain pages

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

There are about 20 apps installed on our shop. Different apps are used on different pages. For example, there are apps which are used on the product page only.

However I see that all apps are loaded on every page. Looking into page source I see JavaScript function `asyncLoad` which is part of built-in `{{ content_for_header }}` variable. This function load scripts for all apps on every page. So, can I restrict this somehow? I mean - to avoid of downloading scripts/css/whatever of apps which I don't use on the specific page. For example, on the home page I need just a couple of apps active, not all 20 of them. Didn't find the answer in docs or Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've already figured out a lot about how Shopify allows apps to load their scripts, so you're most of the way there!

When I've needed to selectively disable apps, I have removed them from the `asyncLoad` function using something like the following:

```
{% capture modified_content_for_header %}{{ content_for_header }}{% endcapture %}
{% if template.name == 'index' %}
  {% assign modified_content_for_header = modified_content_for_header | remove: 'some_app_url.js,' %}
{% endif %}
<!-- If you have a lot of templates you are checking, a case/when using template.name might be appropriate -->
{{ modified_content_for_header }}
```

---

*I like using {% if [template.name](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/template#template-name) == value %} rather than {% if template contains value %} for template checks, as that ensures I don't accidentally get a false positive for a template suffix that contains one of the other template types for some reason, like a `collection.alternate_product_layout` or something silly like that.*

**Disclaimer:** Messing with 3rd party apps by removing their script files may have unexpected side-effects, so always be sure to exercise caution and test thoroughly on an unpublished theme!

Comment: Hi. I have a question related to this answer. I have an app which we can add to the theme code. is there a way to only only install the app on a certain page dynamically? We dont want the user to add the app manually on the page where they want the app

Comment: @YahyaRehman - That's a good question!  You could try looking into the [App snippets & sections](https://shopify.dev/changelog/new-app-snippets-and-app-sections-extensions-released-in-developer-preview) that Shopify recently added - I don't have any experience with those yet, but it might be able to do what you need.